# useState to add property to an object is only leaving me with the last property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to create an empty object, then add properties to this object x number of times within a loop.

I want each property key to be assigned a name based on the loop integer.

I'm always left with only the last value... Plus it seems to be assigning the property key to the name of the variable, rather than the name I'm giving it. I've tried multiple iterations of setState, each with the same result:

```
const [vgJson, setVgJson] = useState({});

for (let i=1; i <= 300; i++) {
  let key = "1234567" + i;
  let newItem = {};
  newItem[key] = {
      "createdDate":"2021-08-15T22:34:28.000",
      "id":key
    }
    let addVg = newItem[key];

    setVgJson({...vgJson, addVg});
}
```

I've tried other methods such as:

```
setVgJson((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      addVg
    }));
```

Gives the same result...

My goal is to return an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "12345671":{"id":"12345671", "createdDate":"2021-08-15T22:35:28.000" },
    "12345672":{"id":"12345672", "createdDate":"2021-08-15T22:35:28.000" }
}
// All the way to 300....
```

I keep ending up with this (from console.log):

```
{addVg: {…}}
     addVg:
     createdDate: "2021-08-15T22:34:28.000"
     id: "1234567300"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

I don't want the key to be addVg. I want it to be the value of the `key` variable.

It keeps just giving me the last property I created in the loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately. Basically, you should avoid setting state in loops.

Comment: You need to just store your result in a temp object in the loop & after loop exits, you can set your state to this temp object.

Comment: @umar Yeah. It all clicked as soon as I stepped out the door for lunch. This is what comes from switching technologies for a few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what I was thinking, as I'm very familiar with this behavior. This is what comes from switching technologies for a few months.

Anyways, declaring an object and setting state outside the loop fixed this up:

```
useEffect(() => {

  let vbObj = {};

  for (let i=1; i <= 300; i++) {
  let key = "1234567" + i;
  
  let addVg = {
      "createdDate":"2021-08-15T22:34:28.000",
      "id":key
    }

    vbObj[key] = addVg;
  }
  setVgJson(vbObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
const [vgJson, setVgJson] = useState({});

for (let i=1; i <= 300; i++) {
  let key = "1234567" + i;
  setVgJson({...vgJson ,
     [key]:{"createdDate":"2021-08-15T22:34:28.000",
            "id":key}
     })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

or u can simply create a copy of object and push the value and set value

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
  let key = "1234567" + i;
  let temp = vgJson;
  temp[key] = {
    createdDate: "2021-08-15T22:34:28.000",
    id: key
  };
  setVgJson(temp);
}
```